# How to retain HTML internal links while sending HTML content as email using python?

Tags: python, html, tableofcontents

I'm trying to send .html content as mail body using Python, everything works except the internal links present in the html file. Internal links are working as expected when I open the file in browser, but in the mail body those links were not navigating to corresponding headers (like Table of contents). I'm using MIMEText() to parse the html content by UTF-8 (I'm not sure this could be the issue)

I've tried to replicate outlook internal page linking using a macro, but it didn't work for this usecase

```py
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()

report_file = open('C:\\Users\\thiru\\python_test_engine\\reports\\goals-wbr.html', encoding="utf8")
html = report_file.read()

part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part)

#s is smtplib object
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#00-team-update">team update</a></li>
    <li><a href="#01-group-1">group 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#02-group-A">group A</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2><a id="#00-team-update">team update</a></h2>
<h4 class="Green" style="color:black" bgcolor="#00FF00">
```

Internal links from HTML file are imported to mail body as hyperlinks, but links not working in the mail

Comment: Please define "not working", and edit you question to add an exemple HTML with links that "doesn't work".

Comment: In given html template, `href="#00-team-update"` will work on browser since it will have a base url to work with but in case of mail box, It doesn't have a base url to work with so on click mail client doesn't know where to redirect. In template, try `href='https://stackoverflow.com'` then It should work.

Comment: @RajmaniArya Thanks. But already 'external links' are working in mail box, I'm facing issues retaining 'internal links'

Comment: Why not modify the HTML to add after the <head> tag a <base> tag that specifies an appropriate base url?

Comment: Adding name attribute instead of id in <h2><a solves the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding name attribute instead of id in  solves the issue.